# Printing Different bibliographies with Different bib files in book class using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, books, back-referencing

How to print different bibliographies with Different bib files in book class? Here is sample outline.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file1.bib}
\addbibresource{file2.bib}
\addbibresource{file3.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
...
...
\printbibliography{file1}
\chapter{Second}
...
...
\printbibliography{file2}
\chapter{Third}
...
...
\printbibliography{file3}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible? If so how? I prefer to avoid chapterbib and/or natbib due to formatting options and compatibility reasons. There are many urls in references which are supported in native way in biblatex.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your chapters in different `refsection`s and use the `<resource>` argument to narrow everything down to a specific `.bib` file. Note that `refsection`s are completely independent, so that a `\nocite{*}` only applies to the current section and its relevant `.bib` file.

I used `backend=biber,` in the example because that only requires a single invocation of the backend. If you absolutely must use BibTeX, the code will also work with `backend=bibtex,` but you will have to run BibTeX on multiple files (follow the instructions in the `.log` file or use a tool like `latexmk` to figure it out for you). Since `biblatex`'s advanced features are only available with Biber anyway, I strongly suggest you look into using Biber.

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-file1.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-file2.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-file3.bib}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  keywords     = {secondary},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname-file1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-file2.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-file3.bib}



\begin{document}
\newrefsection[\jobname-file1.bib]
\chapter{First}
Lorem \autocite{elk}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\newrefsection[\jobname-file2.bib]
\chapter{Second}
Ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\newrefsection[\jobname-file3.bib]
\chapter{Third}
Dolor \autocite{worman}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```